# Custom express-validator

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, express-validator

My custom-validator always return true although when result is not undefined and i have returned false in that case

```
const validatorOptions = {
customValidators: {
    not_exist: (inputParam) => {
        let qry = 'select * from  Users where email = ?';
        let exist= db.query(qry, inputParam, (err, result) => {
            if (err)
                throw err;
            if (result) {
                console.log("Exist");
                return false;
            } else
                return true;
        });
        return exist;

    }
}
```

};

I tried using **Promise**, but still it's not working.

```
const validatorOptions = {
customValidators: {
    isUniqueEmail: (email) => {
        function getRecord(email) {
            return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
                let qry = 'select * from  Users where email = ?';
                db.query(qry, email, (err, result) => {
                    if (err)
                        reject(err);
                    else {
                        resolve(result);
                    }

                });
            });
        };
        getRecord(email).then(function(res) {
            return (res.length == 0);
        }).catch((err) => { throw err; });;

    }
}
```

};

```
req.checkBody('email', 'Email already exist').isUniqueEmail();
```

Comment: Try return the result as a `Promise` instead of regular `return`

Answer (score 0):

That is because you're returning the variable **exist** which is equal to `db.query()` (and always a `truthy` value).

I had some questions about this code (because I don't see how it could run in the current state):

- Seems odd to have `customValidators` as a child to `validatorOptions`, is there a reason for this?
- Is there a reason you're mixing camel and snake case?
- Do you think the custom validator method name could be more descriptive as to its' purpose, such as `isUniqueEmailAddress`?
- Why isn't the SQL statement concatenating the argument into the
- Do you think this code should implement some SQL input cleansing for security reasons?
- Does db.query() really expect 3 arguments??? (I would think it just needs SQL and callback)
- Since db.query() is performing an asynchronous operation, have you considered using Promises?